# I am trying to get every cell in a column populate with a "

Tags: excel

I am trying to get every cell in a column populate with a ", as in 8", 10" and so on. Having the " in the common script causes errors...Obviously, I don't want to type the " in every cell.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a unit of measure and applies to a number. If you want to use the number for calculations, then you should not enter the " sign into the cell at all. Instead use a custom number format, which will allow you to still use the number for calculations without jumping through hoops.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Length is entered as inches. The " sign is not typed but used in the custom format

```
0\"
```

applied to the Length and total cells. Note how the numbers can be used just fine in calculations.

If you are looking for the syntax to enter a " character into a cell using VBA, then be aware that you need to use several " characters to put a " into a string.

```
[A1] = """"
```

Comment: If decimals may or may not be part of the cell value then `General\"` works for a non-fixed decimal point.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just for clarity, I am building tables for work, and I just want to be lazy really, and not enter " on every cell in data entry. I want to be able to just type 10, hit enter, and 10" appears in the cell.

Comment: If a cell already contains the character `"` then it is a lot more work to get the 10 in front of it. Just select the column, apply the custom format mentioned and type the number. Pre-entering the " won't help at all, because you would have to do a lot more typing when entering the number.

Comment: If that helped, please mark the answer as described in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

If you want VBA this can help:

```
Sub addQuotes()
    Dim i
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A20")

    For Each i In rng
        i.Value = i.Value & Chr(34)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Or you can use formulas:

Imagine you got this:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
| Row Index | Data Set | Formula |
+-----------+----------+---------+
|         1 | S        |         |
|         2 | S        |         |
|         3 | S        |         |
|         4 | S        |         |
|         5 | S        |         |
|         6 | S        |         |
|         7 | S        |         |
|         8 | S        |         |
|         9 | S        |         |
|        10 | S        |         |
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

In the formula column you need to put this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,"""")
```

And the resulto will be this:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
| Row Index | Data Set | Formula |
+-----------+----------+---------+
|         1 | S        | S"      |
|         2 | S        | S"      |
|         3 | S        | S"      |
|         4 | S        | S"      |
|         5 | S        | S"      |
|         6 | S        | S"      |
|         7 | S        | S"      |
|         8 | S        | S"      |
|         9 | S        | S"      |
|        10 | S        | S"      |
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Or if you want to user inches format: `0\"` as suggested by @teylyn then just use that custom format, and you only add the `"` to the format not to the number it self, and the you can use it as a number.

[image]